# blueman error No adapters found

Tags: networking, drivers, usb, bluetooth

Please anyone know how to solve this problem.
I was trying to connect bluetooth speakers/ mouse.
I tried lot of methods but not solved.
Below is some information what i had tried.

```
aejaz@aejaz-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$ lsusb; dmesg | egrep -i 'blue|firm'
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 1bcf:2c9b Sunplus Innovation Technology Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:b009 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 

[   24.983563] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload((null)) tmp_ps=0
[   24.983565] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload fw: FW_NIC, size: 26498
[   24.983566] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload: fw_ver=1d fw_subver=0002 
sig=0x23d1, Month=04, Date=14, Hour=11, Minute=13
[   24.983566] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload(): Shift for fw header!
[   24.983568] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload by IO write!
[   24.986044] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload: download FW count:1
[   25.004247] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload success. write_fw:1, 24ms
[   25.004248] RTW:  <=== rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload()
[   29.490025] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[   29.490027] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[   29.490031] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[   33.157484] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload(wlo1) tmp_ps=0
[   33.157485] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload fw: FW_NIC, size: 26498
[   33.157489] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload: fw_ver=1d fw_subver=0002 sig=0x23d1, Month=04, Date=14, Hour=11, Minute=13
[   33.157489] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload(): Shift for fw header!
[   33.157560] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload by IO write!
[   33.159957] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload: download FW count:1
[   33.178160] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload success. write_fw:1, 20ms
[   33.178161] RTW:  <=== rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload()
[   35.091787] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload(wlo1) tmp_ps=0
[   35.091787] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload fw: FW_NIC, size: 26498
[   35.091789] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload: fw_ver=1d fw_subver=0002 sig=0x23d1, Month=04, Date=14, Hour=11, Minute=13
[   35.091789] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload(): Shift for fw header!
[   35.091873] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload by IO write!
[   35.094271] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload: download FW count:1
[   35.112474] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload success. write_fw:1, 24ms
[   35.112475] RTW:  <=== rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload()
[   58.021783] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload(wlo1) tmp_ps=0
[   58.021784] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload fw: FW_NIC, size: 26498
[   58.021785] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload: fw_ver=1d fw_subver=0002 sig=0x23d1, Month=04, Date=14, Hour=11, Minute=13
[   58.021786] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload(): Shift for fw header!
[   58.021869] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload by IO write!
[   58.024341] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload: download FW count:1
[   58.042544] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload success. write_fw:1, 20ms
[   58.042544] RTW:  <=== rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload()
[   79.518970] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload(wlo1) tmp_ps=0
[   79.518971] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload fw: FW_NIC, size: 26498
[   79.518972] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload: fw_ver=1d fw_subver=0002 sig=0x23d1, Month=04, Date=14, Hour=11, Minute=13
[   79.518973] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload(): Shift for fw header!
[   79.519056] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload by IO write!
[   79.521539] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload: download FW count:1
[   79.539817] RTW: rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload success. write_fw:1, 20ms
[   79.539818] RTW:  <=== rtl8723d_FirmwareDownload()
```

---

```
aejaz@aejaz-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$ inxi -Fxzd
System:    Host: aejaz-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx Kernel: 4.15.0-36-generic x86_64 (64 bit gcc: 5.4.0)
Desktop: Unity 7.4.0 (Gtk 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.3)
Distro: Ubuntu 16.04 xenial
Machine:   System: HP product: HP Laptop 15-bs1xx v: Type1ProductConfigId
Mobo: HP model: 832A v: 23.61 Bios: Insyde v: F.42 date: 08/06/2018
CPU:       Quad core Intel Core i5-8250U (-HT-MCP-) cache: 6144 KB
           flags: (lm nx sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3 vmx) bmips: 14400
           clock speeds: max: 3400 MHz 1: 902 MHz 2: 1804 MHz 3: 1322 MHz
           4: 1925 MHz 5: 1803 MHz 6: 1935 MHz 7: 1644 MHz 8: 1494 MHz

Graphics:  Card: Intel Device 5917 bus-ID: 00:02.0
           Display Server: X.Org 1.19.3 drivers: (unloaded: fbdev,vesa)
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.01hz
           GLX Renderer: Mesa DRI Intel UHD Graphics 620 (Kabylake GT2)
           GLX Version: 3.0 Mesa 18.0.5 Direct Rendering: Yes
Audio:     Card Intel Device 9d71 driver: snd_hda_intel bus-ID: 00:1f.3
           Sound: Advanced Linux Sound Architecture v: k4.15.0-36-generic
Network:   Card-1: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
           driver: r8169 v: 2.3LK-NAPI port: 4000 bus-ID: 01:00.0
           IF: eno1 state: down mac: <filter>
           Card-2: Realtek Device d723
           driver: rtl8723de v: v5.1.1.8_21285.20171026 port: 3000
           bus-ID: 02:00.0
           IF: wlo1 state: up speed: N/A duplex: N/A mac: <filter>
Drives:    HDD Total Size: 1000.2GB (4.4% used)
           ID-1: /dev/sda model: ST1000LM035 size: 1000.2GB
           Optical: /dev/sr0 model: hp DVDRW  DA8AESH
           rev: XH6M dev-links: cdrom,cdrw,dvd,dvdrw
           Features: speed: 24x multisession: yes
           audio: yes dvd: yes rw: cd-r,cd-rw,dvd-r state: running
Partition: ID-1: / size: 235G used: 34G (16%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda7
           ID-2: swap-1 size: 8.50GB used: 0.00GB (0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda8
RAID:      No RAID devices: /proc/mdstat, md_mod kernel module present
Sensors:   System Temperatures: cpu: 38.5C mobo: 29.8C
           Fan Speeds (in rpm): cpu: N/A
Info:      Processes: 243 Uptime: 1:24 Memory: 1610.9/7893.5MB
           Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Gcc sys: 5.4.0
           Client: Shell (bash 4.3.481) inxi: 2.2.35
```

---

```
aejaz@aejaz-HP-Laptop-15-bs1xx:~$ bluetoothctl
[bluetooth]# list
[bluetooth]# show
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# power on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# scan on
No default controller available
[bluetooth]# exit
```